# How can I get out of the loop?

Tags: arduino

I'd like to get out of the loop in my Arduino project. Currently I am programming a digital watch, everything works just fine but I wanted to add options menu by clicking a button, but after clicking it nothing pops up even if I have something inside the code. Take a look at it. I don't know how to write it better. If you have some ideas, please you could rewrite some parts of the code and explain why you did so. Thanks forwardly.

Please do not mind s = s + 1, I wanted it like that.

```
#include "LiquidCrystal.h"
#include <EEPROM.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(12,11,5,4,3,2);

int h = 0;
int m = 0;
int s = 0;
int right = 8;
int left = 9;
int buttonStateLeft = 0;
String when;


uint8_t EEPROMaddress_sec = 1;
uint8_t EEPROMaddress_min = 2;
uint8_t EEPROMaddress_hour = 3;

bool clockShown = true;
bool menuShown = false;

void setup()
{
  lcd.begin(16,2);
  pinMode(right, INPUT);
  pinMode(left, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{

  if(menuShown)
  {
        lcd.setCursor(0,0);
        lcd.print("jozo je kkt");
        delay(200);
  }


  if(clockShown) {

      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      buttonStateLeft = digitalRead(left);

      if(buttonStateLeft == HIGH)
      {
        clockShown = false;
        menuShown = true;
        lcd.clear();
      }

      s = EEPROM.read(EEPROMaddress_sec);
      m = EEPROM.read(EEPROMaddress_min);
      h = EEPROM.read(EEPROMaddress_hour);

      s = s + 1;

      if(h > 12)
      when = "PM";
      if(h < 12)
      when = "AM";
      if(h == 12)
      when = "PM";

      lcd.print("Cas: ");
      if(h<10)lcd.print("0");
      lcd.print(h);
      lcd.print(":");
      if(m<10)lcd.print("0");
      lcd.print(m);
      lcd.print(":");
      if(s<10)lcd.print("0");
      lcd.print(s);
      lcd.print(" ");
      lcd.print(when);

      if(s == 60)
      {
        s = 0;
        m = m+1;
      }

      if(m == 60)
      {
        s = 0;
        m = 0;
        h = h+1;
      }
      if(h == 24)
      {
        m = 0;
        s = 0;
        h = 0;
      }

      EEPROM.write(EEPROMaddress_sec, s);
      EEPROM.write(EEPROMaddress_min, m);
      EEPROM.write(EEPROMaddress_hour, h);

      delay(1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: You say you don't see anything change when you press the button. Which button do you press? In your code you only check for the left button (so you would have to press the left button). 

Try holding down the button for longer than one second because your arduino sleeps for 1000 milliseconds at the end of your loop. So when you press while the arduion sleeps, the arduino wont notice it.

Comment: I know, this works for me but when I hold it down my LCD just lags and doesn't work. I don't see the text displayed there (in menuShown). That's the problem. I hope you help me find a solution

Comment: you can add `return;` to jump out of the loop()

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that you will have to use Interrupts, note that you must connect your button to an interrupt pin (not every pin is an interrupt pin) you can google "what are the interrupt pins of 'your_card_name' ", the code would have to change, you can follow these :

In the setup function replace :

```
 pinMode(left, INPUT);
```

by :

```
 attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(left), switchMode, RISING);
```

add this function before setup(){...}

```
 int lastPressTime=millis();
 void switchMode(){ // function called when the button is pressed
    if((millis()-lastPressTime)>60){ // for debouncing
     clockShown = false;
     menuShown = true;
     lcd.clear();
     lastPressTime=millis();
    }
 }
```

and remove this part from your code : (the one in the loop() function)

```
        buttonStateLeft = digitalRead(left);

  if(buttonStateLeft == HIGH)
  {
    clockShown = false;
    menuShown = true;
    lcd.clear();
  }
```